# Images on mobile devices are blurry when using 4G

Tags: responsive-design, wordpress

I noticed my images on a website are blurry when using a mobile device. This occurs only when I'm using 4G and NOT when I'm connected to wi-fi. If I'm connected to wi-fi, the images look fine.

I realize a slower connection may be causing this, but I'm curious how I can fix it.  I downloaded a "Resize Image Quality" plugin for Wordpress and that didn't work.

Are there any changes that can be made to CSS to fix this issue? I'm never had this issue before with Wordpress or any other CMS.

Here's a link just in case it's needed: http://bit.ly/1J1vwFB

Comment: I'd wonder if your ISP is proxying the images to reduce bandwidth use. Are you able to load your site over HTTPS to prevent them from modifying things?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, I used chrome with network throttling and emulating different phones.. It looks fine, have you tried other phones?

Comment: Not on an Android yet. I'll try to find one.